# Integral inequality for sin function

Tags: integral-inequality

Let $0<r<1$ and $t\geq 0$ real numbers. Is it true that $$\int_t^{t+r} \sin(x)\, dx \leq \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{r}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{r}{2}}\sin(x)\, dx \,? $$

I suspect that yes, since both integration intervals have length $r$ and $\sin$ has maximum in second one (RHS).

Hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to do it (though unelegant) would be to write out the solutions to the integrals explicitly. So, you are asking us to prove that:
$$\cos(t)-\cos(r+t)\leq \cos(\pi/2-r/2)-\cos(\pi/2+r/2)$$
This is true, since by one of the [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), namely:
$$\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)=-2\sin\left[\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)\right]\sin\left[\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)\right]$$
We have that:
$$\cos(t)-\cos(r+t)=2\sin(r/2)\sin(r/2+t)$$
And:
$$\cos(\pi/2-r/2)-\cos(\pi/2+r/2)=2\sin(r/2)$$
And fortunately, since $0<r<1$, we have that $\sin(r/2)> 0$ and since $r/2+t$ is a real number, $\sin(r/2+t)\leq 1$.

Comment: Fortunately, $\sin\leq 1$!!!

Comment: Indeed. It would be nice however if someone could figure out a solution to this problem without having to explicitly solve the integrals.

Comment: Sometimes, hard problems have simple solutions... and usually we don't look to the simple ones. Thanks.